# hibernate single foreign key for many tables

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to add single foreign key for two tables.Lets say have three tables `Vendor`,`Customer` and `Contact`.Want to make contact as an `@OneToMany` relation.
So to to this thought of taking a common id called object_id and to object_type to know is it vendor or customer.

in contact class

```
@Column(name = "object_type", nullable = false)
private String objectType;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="object_id",referencedColumnName="id" ,insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Vendor vendor;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="object_id",referencedColumnName="id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Customer customer;
```

But it is not adding foreign key for both vendor and customer table.
Only One sql Hibernate if firing

alter table contact 
       add constraint FKj3890q987sngeflip2ex9b85j 
       foreign key (object_id) 
       references customer (id)

Can i do this way or is there any other better way to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

if(contact is a one to many relationship)

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="object_id",referencedColumnName="id" ,insertable=false, updatable=false)
private List<Vendor> vendors;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="object_id",referencedColumnName="id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private List<Customer> customer;
```

Else if contact is many to one, then Rather than in contact class, define the foreign keys in the vendor and customer classes which each will have a field like

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="object_id" ,insertable=false, updatable=false)
private List<Contact> contacts;
```

Also keep an eye on LazyFetch or best is to set it to false

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```